# Graph Theory Problem [3]

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is a connected graph with chromatic number $\chi (G)\geq 4$, then show that $G$ can be contracted to the complete graph $K_4$.

The more general form of this claim is as follows: If $G$ is a connected graph with chromatic number $\chi (G)\geq p$, then show that $G$ can be contracted to the complete graph $K_p$.

I have been able to prove this statement for $p=1,2,3$ but I have had not much success with $p=4.$ There is a paper by Dirac, which gives the proof and it can be only viewed by members on this [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s1-27.1.85/full). So if anyone has access kindly share the proof. Or else suggest a way by which I can go about proving this result.

Comment: I have seen similar to this problem yesterday. did you check? This one. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254560/graph-theory-proof-based-problem

Comment: @SaeidAli This problem is related to that problem but is quite different. However, I have realized that this result will help me solve that problem and so in some sense this is like a sub-problem.

Comment: Wish that I could help. good luck.

Comment: @SaeidAli does your university or you have access to Wiley Online Library?

Comment: The paper by Dirac can be read by members who have access to the Wiley Online Library.

Comment: Here I do not. Sorry.

Comment: Anyways, thank you for your prompt comments!

Comment: It was easy to find. give me your email address. or tell me a way that I can send it to you.

Comment: @SaeidAli My email address is shrey183@gmail.com. Thank you for your efforts...

Comment: I just send it. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who do not have access to the Dirac Paper, I will sketch a proof (I suspect it will not be the same as the Dirac paper). It is well known that graphs not containing a $K_{4}$-minor are the class of series-parallel graphs, and have treewidth less than $3$. Graphs with treewidth less than $2$ can be built up from clique sums of graphs having at most $3$ vertices (this is an alternative definition of treewidth).

Here a clique sum of two graphs $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ is the identification of $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ on some clique, and then possibly removing some edges if desired. Now clearly graphs on at most $3$-vertices are $3$-colourable and taking two three colourable graphs and performing a clique sum, it is not too hard to see the resulting graph is $3$-colourable. Therefore, all $K_{4}$-minor-free graphs are $3$-colourable, which completes the proof.

Edit: This problem is the well known Hadwinger's conjecture, which is open for everything bigger than $K_{6}$-minors.